# learning plyr ddply - applying function up to a point

Tags: r, plyr

I am learning plyr package, I am using inbuilt "baseball" dataset for my exercises. Here is the example data (the whole data frame is rather wide, so I only posted the part that is relevant from the exercise point of view)  :

```
data(baseball)
baseball <- baseball[with(baseball, order(id, year)), ]
rownames(baseball) <- NULL
head(baseball[,c("id","year", "ab")])

         id year  ab
1 aaronha01 1954 468
2 aaronha01 1955 602
3 aaronha01 1956 609
4 aaronha01 1957 615
5 aaronha01 1958 601
6 aaronha01 1959 629
```

What I want to do, is to add another column to that data frame, that will contain average "number of times at bat" (ab variable) up to date, so for 3 first rows it would look like this:

```
         id year  ab  atb
1 aaronha01 1954 468  468
2 aaronha01 1955 602  535
3 aaronha01 1956 609  559.6667
```

Now I know I should use ddply and transform function, but I have no idea how the syntax should look for getting mean from values up to certain index:

```
baseball <- ddply(baseball, ~ id, transform, atb = ???)
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You may consider the successor of `plyr`package: `dplyr`. There you find the function `cummean`. Or just `base`: `cumsum(df$ab) / seq_along(df$ab)`.

Comment: Thanks, the second syntax was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method with `data.table`.

```
# load data.table
library(data.table)
# cast data.frame as data.table
setDT(baseball)

# perform the calculation
baseball[, atb := cumsum(ab) / seq_len(.N), by=id]
```

Here, atb is calculated as the cumulative sum of bats (`cumsum(ab)`) divided by the number of years that the id is observed up until that point (`seq_len(.N)`), and the calculation is performed by id.

this returns

```
head(baseball[,c("id","year", "ab", "atb")])
          id year  ab      atb
1: aaronha01 1954 468 468.0000
2: aaronha01 1955 602 535.0000
3: aaronha01 1956 609 559.6667
4: aaronha01 1957 615 573.5000
5: aaronha01 1958 601 579.0000
6: aaronha01 1959 629 587.3333
```

---

In base R, you can accomplish this with `tapply`

```
baseball$atb2 <- unlist(tapply(baseball$ab, baseball$id,
                               function(i) cumsum(i) / seq_along(i)))

all.equal(baseball$atb, baseball$atb2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
baseball %>%
       group_by(id) %>%
       mutate(atb = cummean(ab))
```

---

Or we can use `ave` from `base R`

```
baseball$atb <- with(baseball, ave(ab, id, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x)/seq_along(x)))
```